# Group and Join Linq statement wont pass to my view from controller

Tags: c#, linq

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestingMainPage.Models.SummaryModel>

@if (Model.Count() > 1 )
{//Do something}
else
{//Do something else}
```

The error involved:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type  'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType11`4[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestingMainPage.Models.SummaryModel]'.
```

Which is caused by the linq statement...

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this linq statement? I am still new to linq and trying to figure it out..

For some reason I can run it in Linqer but it wont actually pass the model to my view in my project? Which I am assuming because there is something wrong with the Linq statement, because if I switch it up to a very simple select then it will pass the model..

```
        var BeginDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("d") + " 2:00:00";
        var EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " 2:00:00";
        DateTime Start = Convert.ToDateTime(BeginDate);
        DateTime End = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);

      var TestLinq = (from a in db.seqexp_master
                      join b in db.seqexp_detail on a.recid equals b.recid into b_join
                      from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where
                        a.shipto == "1020" &&
                        (new string[] { "a", "c" }).Contains(a.status) &&
                        a.active == 1 &&
                        b.active == 1 &&
                        a.datetimestamp >= Start &&
                        a.datetimestamp <= End
                      group new { a, b } by new
                      {
                          a.recid,
                          a.datetimestamp,
                          a.status
                      } into g
                      orderby
                        g.Key.recid descending
                      select new
                      {
                          Recid = g.Key.recid,
                          datetimestamp = g.Key.datetimestamp,
                          status = g.Key.status,
                          Qty = g.Sum(p => p.b.qty)
                      });
return View(TestLinq);
```

Any help is appreciated :D 
Thanks

I dont think you would need to see my Model either, but just incase:

```
   public class SummaryModel
{
    public DateTime datetimestamp { get; set; }
    public char status { get; set; }
    public int? Recid { get; set; }
    public int? Qty { get; set; }
    public int? test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please specify *exactly* what the errors are. Don't make us guess.

Comment: The error is the linq statement... It is wrong...

Comment: But here is the error caused by my If (Model.Count() > 1) in my view....Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'TestingMainPage.Models.SummaryModel' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'TestingMainPage.Models.SummaryModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That's really not very *exact*, is it? Is that what the compiler says? "Your LINQ statement is wrong"? I suspect not.

Comment: Right, that's much more like it. Not please put that into your question.

Comment: It is caused because there is nothing in Model.Count so my linq statement is not being passed through to my view

Comment: Next problem: you're getting an error in the view, but you haven't shown us anything about the view, including what the declared model type is if any... Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: The problem is the linq statement, I dont understand how any of this is relevant... I have already stated that if I switch the linq statement to a simple select everything works fine...

Comment: Well I doubt that that really fixes it, unless you've really got a `Count()` method in `SummaryModel`. I suspect you want `@model IEnumerable<TestingMainPage.Models.SummaryModel>`

Comment: Well I would change it to that if I do the simple select and it would work fine...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that comment at all. Your view looks like the first thing to fix, as I've suggested - then you can update your post with whatever the error becomes. Maybe someone else will be able to help you further, but I'm afraid I can't spend any more time trying to work out exactly what problems you're facing...

Comment: I have changed it to the exact error

Comment: Right, and now it's easy enough to answer. It's a shame it took an hour to get that level of detail...

Comment: I am still learning I apologize, I did not think it would even be necessary but I now understand why it was. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem, at the end of your query:

```
select new
{
    Recid = g.Key.recid,
    datetimestamp = g.Key.datetimestamp,
    status = g.Key.status,
    Qty = g.Sum(p => p.b.qty)
}
```

That's an anonymous type, but your view wants an `IEnumerable<SummaryModel>`. It's not clear what `SummaryModel` is, but perhaps you want:

```
select new SummaryModel
{
    Recid = g.Key.recid,
    datetimestamp = g.Key.datetimestamp,
    status = g.Key.status,
    Qty = g.Sum(p => p.b.qty)
}
```

(If so, I strongly recommend that you fix your property names to follow normal .NET conventions...)